# pdf address labels based on sql data only returns 1

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have used fpdf coding to create a pdf document. The document is address labels of people in the database 'test'. At the moment there is 3 rows but my code will only fetch 1 which is the recent entered one.

How can I make it fetch them all?

```
<?php
require('PDF_Label.php');
require('db_connect.php');

/*------------------------------------------------
To create the object, 2 possibilities:
either pass a custom format via an array
or use a built-in AVERY name
------------------------------------------------*/

// Example of custom format
// $pdf = new PDF_Label(array('paper-size'=>'A4', 'metric'=>'mm', 'marginLeft'=>1, 'marginTop'=>1, 'NX'=>2, 'NY'=>7, 'SpaceX'=>0, 'SpaceY'=>0, 'width'=>99, 'height'=>38, 'font-size'=>14));

// Standard format
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM test");


while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$driver = $row['driver'];
$fline = $row['fline'];
$sline = $row['sline'];
$town = $row['town'];
$town = $row['postcode'];
$other = $row['other'];

}

$pdf = new PDF_Label('L7163');

$pdf->AddPage();


//ote

// Print labels

    $text = sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s %s %s", "$driver", "$fline", "$sline", "$town", "$postcode", "$other");
    $pdf->Add_Label($text);



$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're establishing a DB connection when calling db_connect.php, but you're not referencing that connection in your function call:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($connection, "Select * from test");
```